# Can't add email to Campaign Monitor API?

Tags: ruby, api, httparty, campaign-monitor

I am trying to create some simple Ruby code to add emails using the Campaign Monitor API. Below is my code.

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

def request
    url = 'https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.1/subscribers/MYLISTID.json'
    auth = {:username => 'MYAPIKEY', :password => 'x'}
    response = HTTParty.post(url,
                  :basic_auth => auth, :body => {
                      'EmailAddress' => 'mike@hotmail.com',
                      'Name' => 'Test',
                      'Resubscribe' => true,
                      'RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders' => true
                  })
    puts response
    puts response.code
end
request
```

I can connect with the API. However, when I try to add the email I am getting the following response.

> {"Code"=>400, "Message"=>"Failed to deserialize your request. 
>   Please check the documentation and try again. 
>   Fields in error: subscriber"} 
>      400

When I change the request to `get` instead of `put`
my response is:

> {"Code"=>1, "Message"=>"Invalid Email Address"}

I can't understand what I am doing wrong as I have followed the documentation on the [Campaign Monitor API](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything setup correctly, you just need to turn the body of the post into a json string.

```
  response = HTTParty.post(url,
    :basic_auth => auth, :body => {
       'EmailAddress' => 'mike@hotmail.com',
       'Name' => 'Test',
       'Resubscribe' => true,
       'RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders' => true
     }.to_json)
```

I'd like to point out that a Campaign Monitor API gem also exists that will do all of that work for you.

[Campaign Monitor API Gem](https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-ruby)